# Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.5.3)

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js

I am new to this space and in the process of learning Solidity and Javascript. So please bear with me.
I was executing simple node script and stumbled across this error.
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.5.3)
at Logger.makeError (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)
at Logger.throwError (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)
at JsonRpcProvider. (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:517:54)
at step (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
at Object.throw (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
at rejected (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
reason: 'could not detect network',
code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
event: 'noNetwork'

Any fix to this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you search for the error message? [This is the first item when I searched just now](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1316) and it specifically mentions Ethers.

Comment: Yes already, but when changing the input I get another error
TypeError: provider.ready is not a function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.5.3)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:517:54)
at step (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)

Comment: at Object.throw (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/Users/code/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}